# Read a secret from a PKCS12 file with .NET

Tags: .net, encryption, public-key-encryption, pkcs#12

According to RSA's [docs](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11301-pkcs-12v1-1-personal-information-exchange-syntax-wp.pdf) on the PKCS12 format, it can be used to store 'miscellaneous secrets'.  From the specification:

```
4.2.5.  The SecretBag Type

   Each of the user's miscellaneous personal secrets is contained in an
   instance of SecretBag, which holds an object identifier-dependent
   value.  Note that a SecretBag contains only one secret.

   SecretBag ::= SEQUENCE {
       secretTypeId   BAG-TYPE.&id ({SecretTypes}),
       secretValue    [0] EXPLICIT BAG-TYPE.&Type ({SecretTypes}
                          {@secretTypeId})
   }

   SecretTypes BAG-TYPE ::= {
       ... -- For future extensions
   }

   Implementers can add values to this set at their own discretion.
```

I'd like to read such secrets using .NET, but I can't figure out how with X509Certificate2, or even if it's possible. Can it be done?

Comment: How much work are you willing to do? The bouncycastle Java library has classes for working with PKCS#12 format, and the C# library seems to have most of what's in the Java library. The C# library is mostly undocumented, so you typically need to look first in the [Javadocs](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/index.html) and then hunt around in the C# source code.